# What will happen when the code signing certificate expires?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

We have 2 web applications and a WCF service using a strongly named DLL. The certificate used for signing this DLL is going to expire and we have not got the replacement certificate yet.

Can anyone please tell if there could be any problem with the applications, if we continue to use this strongly named DLL after the certificate has expired.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When talking about signing DLLs it is necessary to distinguish two cases:

- Giving assembly a strong name
- Creating an authenticode signature

Certificate used for giving a strong name can expire and it does not affect strong naming process itself and resulting assembly afterwards. Because only public/private key pair is used to give a strong name. .SNK files that are typically used to keep keys for strong naming are just container for public/private keys.

Authenticode signature requires full certificate file and you cannot use expired certificate to create an authenticode signature.
But there are two methods to create authenticode signature: with verified timestamp or without.
If DLL was signed without verified timestamp, then its signature will become 'invalid' when certificate used to sign the DLL expires. If DLL was signed using verified timestamp, then the DLL will be valid forever.

So, in your case if you are talking only about strong names, then everything will be functional.

If you are using Authenticode signatures and do not use verified timestamps, then your DLLs will not have valid signature after certificate expires, but they still will be functional. Although, e.g. ClickOnce behaves a little different when DLLs to be distributed have valid/invalid Authenticode signature.